# What is the fastest way to get basic templating in PHP, a la Struts Tiles?

Tags: php, templates

I'm new to PHP, and I'm looking to do what I'd normally do with Struts Tiles in JSP. I'm looking for something like:
Template.php:

```
<html><body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="contents">
  <#insert sectionName="pageContents">
 </div>
</body></html>
```

Content.php:

```
<#template name="Template.php">
 <#section name="pageContents">
  <div>
   <?php doSomething(); ?>
  </div>
 </#section>
</#template>
```

Such that a request for Content.php returns the contents of Content.php included into Template.php appropriately. I'm looking for the fastest solution in terms of minimal installation/configuration time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any number of php templating systems, but I'd recommend you use php's native capabilities. There's no additional performance overhead, and nothing to install or configure.

For instance to mimic the example above, you could do something like:

Template.inc:

```
<html><body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="contents">
  <?php print $pageContents
  //Or if your php installation supports short tags
  //<?=$pageContents?>
  ?>
 </div>
</body></html>
```

Content.php

```
<?php
  $something = doSomething();

  $pageContents = <<<CONTENT

<div>
  $something
</div>

CONTENT;

  include "template.inc";
```

Of course, there are lots of other ways of accomplishing the example above. That's another upside to using native capabilities - you can arrange and configure your own templating system to work the way you prefer.

Comment: Awesome. Kills my syntax highlighting, but it suits my purposes for the time being, and it should be easy enough to move to another template engine once I've done some more reading.

Comment: One more thing, you should really look at configuring php to support short tags: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag


Also, I would highly recommend using the alternative syntax for control structures embedded into templates:
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Smarty: Template Engine](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 3):

I think [Smarty](http://smarty.php.net) might be a bit overkill in your case, since you ask for a basic PHP templating.

You could take a look at [Lerdorf's article on the No-framework MVC framework](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html) or you could go for one of these template engines:

- [PHPTAL](http://phptal.motion-twin.com/) (although some aspects of the PHPTAL syntax is on the edge of insanity)
- [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/)
- [Savant3](http://phpsavant.com/yawiki/index.php?area=savant3)

Without knowing anything about Struts I think I'd check out Twig first. Although it is a fairly new project I think that it has some really nice features that you might be interested in.

Comment: I really appreciate the use of Twig

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've found every PHP templating overkill. The price of learning and keeping up with the templating engine is just too high. It's often much easier to do it in PHP, with enabled short (ASP-style) tags if you're into that.

If you want, you can wrap the PHP templating in a simple class yourself, or use this:

- http://mariz.org/blog/2005/jun/21/the-php-native-template-engine/

Still want a "real template"? Check out H2O, it looks nice (but I still think it's overkill)

- http://www.h2o-template.org/

Good luck!